# Error when configure HTTPS in WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf, https, wcf-endpoint

I have a Wcf Service in VS 2010, .NET 4.0.

IIS site is virtual directory.

I try configure it and access it using https

> https://pruebaslba.xxxx.net/ServicioPyS/Service.svc?wsdl

But I get error

```
Could not find a base address that matches scheme https for the endpoint with binding WSHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http].
```

or

```
Could not find a base address that matches scheme https for the endpoint with binding BasicHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http].
```

Googleing, I have seen several alternatives about configurations: serviceMetadata, bindings, baseAddresses, ..

I try different configurations, but I get the same error:

**serviceMetadata**

```
<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false or true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
```

**bindings**

I use `<security mode="Transport">`

```
 <bindings>

      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="SecureTransportOnly">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
          </security>
        </binding>

        <binding name="NoSecure">
          <security mode="None"><transport clientCredentialType="None"/></security>
        </binding>

      </basicHttpBinding>

      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="SecureTransportOnly">
          <security mode="Transport">
              <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
          </security>
        </binding>

      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

**endpoint**

```
 <endpoint
            address=""
            binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="SecureTransportOnly"
            name="xxxActualServiceEndPoint"
            bindingNamespace="https://pruebaslba.xxxx.net/ServicioPyS"
            contract="IxxxActualService">
```

**mex**

```
<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding o mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
```

And I tried too:

```
  <!--<host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add  baseAddress="https://pruebaslba.xxxx.net o https://pruebaslba.xxxx.net/ServicioPyS"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>-->

          <!--<identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>-->
```

I tried, I think, almost configurations that I've found in forums. I don't know the solution.

**UPDATE**
I get more information about it.
The website is in 2 servers (PreProduction environment): **preiis01 and preiis02**. **SSL is not enabled.**

I can Access to http://preiis01/ServicioPyS/Service.svc?wsdl 
All is OK by http.

https://pruebaslba.xxxx.net/ServicioPyS/Service.svc?wsdl is public url about NLB (load balanced, I think, F5). In NLB, SSL is configured. I dont know more information, only IT departament has all information.

The problem is about WSDL

**http://preiis01/ServicioPyS/Service.svc?wsdl**

```
<wsdl:service name="ActualService">

<wsdl:port name="ActualServiceEndPoint"binding="i0:ActualServiceEndPoint">

<soap:addresslocation="http://preiis01/ServicioPyS/Service.svc/Service.svc" />

</wsdl:port>

</wsdl:service>
```

url WSDL in NLB hast problema with **soap:address location** part and is not generated right (set http, and not https)

**https://pruebaslba.xxxx.net/ServicioPyS/Service.svc?wsdl**

```
<wsdl:service name="ActualService">

<wsdl:port name="ActualServiceEndPoint"binding="i0:ActualServiceEndPoint">

<soap:addresslocation="http://pruebaslba.xxxx.net/ServicioPyS/Service.svc/Service.svc" />

</wsdl:port>

</wsdl:service>
```

Quickly solution was modify manually WSDL (singlefile) and set **https** in **soap:addresslocation** part, in new url *https://pruebaslba.xxxx.net/ServicioPyS/WSDL/ServiceWsdlModificado.Single.wsdl*

**https://pruebaslba.xxxx.net/ServicioPyS/WSDL/ServiceWsdlModificado.Single.wsdl**

```
<wsdl:service name="ActualService">

<wsdl:port name="ActualServiceEndPoint"binding="tns:ActualServiceEndPoint">

<soap:addresslocation="https://pruebaslba.xxxx.net/ServicioPyS/Service.svc/Service.svc"/>

</wsdl:port>

    </wsdl:service>
```

I think, there is another good solution with good practices. I don't know.

Website in IIS has not SSL enabled, and NLB has SSL.

Maybe “SSL pass-through” , I don't know

http://blog.tonysneed.com/2012/06/18/building-scalable-and-secure-wcf-services/

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you add https binding for your website in IIS?

Comment: @Thuan SSL not enabled in website IIS. Only in NLB F5. Maybe useful SSL pass-through, I don't know about it. Site binding is ***http   hostname: pruebaslba.xxxx.net and port 80** is url about NLB (Load Balanced, F5) ***

Answer (score 0):

There error says that your base address uses the 'http' scheme, when it needs instead to use 'https.'  When hosting in IIS, the address is configured in IIS, rather than the hosts element in config.

That means you need to set up SSL in IIS: http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/how-to-set-up-ssl-on-iis.

Then open Visual Studio as Administrator, then go to the Web tab of project properties and change the base address there to use https with Local IIS.  VS will create a virtual directory for you with the https scheme.

Comment: **https ://pruebaslba.xxxx.net/ServicioPyS/Service.svc?wsdl** is url about NLB (Load Balanced, F5)

Comment: If you are using a load balancer, then see my blog post on building scalable and secure WCF services: http://blog.tonysneed.com/2012/06/18/building-scalable-and-secure-wcf-services

Comment: Essentially what you have to do in this situation is "fool" WCF into thinking the binding transport is secure when in fact it is not.  But what is important here is that SSL is used to secure traffic to the NLB, but from the NLB to the WCF server, you should use ipSec to secure the transport.  This will give you security and scalability.